# Using Changing Integers with UserInput SQL database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm very new to Java so please forgive any mistakes I make.

I'm currently developing an automated TODO list application that sorts through a list of tasks inputted by the user and prioritizes the more important ones.

After the user has added the task, it will be added into an **SQLite database**. I'd like to know how I could associate an Integer with each individual task.

For example:
Say there's an Integer called **Priority** which has a default value of **10**. With each task that's added they begin with a default value of **Priority** = 10 but change according to user demand.

So if one task's default value is **Priority** = 10, **Priority** could increase 11, whereas another task on the same list that starts at **Priority** = 10 may be reduced to **Priority** = 9. I'm very unsure as to how I can make every task added to the database have an individual value which changes regularly.

If you would like me to expand on this further I would be happy to as my explanation may be confusing.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use a TRIGGER [SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

For example, consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tasks;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, user_reference INTEGER, priority DEFAULT 10);
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS set_task_priority;

-- Create the Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS set_task_priority 
    AFTER INSERT ON tasks
    WHEN ((SELECT count() FROM tasks WHERE user_reference = new.user_reference) > 3)
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE tasks SET priority = new.priority + (SELECT  count() FROM  tasks WHERE user_reference = new.user_reference)
        WHERE ID = new.ID
     ;
    END;

-- Add some data to test the trigger
INSERT INTO tasks (user_reference,name) VALUES 
    (1,'CLEAN'),(1,'TIDY'),(1,'VACUMN'),(1,'WASH'),(1,'THINK'),
    (2,'CLEAN'),(2,'TIDY'),(2,'VACUMN'),(2,'WASH'),
    (3,'CLEAN'),(3,'TIDY'),(3,'VACUMN'),(3,'WASH'),(3,'THINK'),(3,'STUDY'),
    (3,'CLEAN'),(3,'TIDY'),(3,'VACUMN'),(3,'WASH'),(3,'THINK'),(3,'STUDY'),
    (3,'CLEAN'),(3,'TIDY'),(3,'VACUMN'),(3,'WASH'),(3,'THINK'),(3,'STUDY'),
    (3,'CLEAN'),(3,'TIDY'),(3,'VACUMN'),(3,'WASH'),(3,'THINK'),(3,'STUDY')
;
INSERT INTO tasks (user_reference,name) VALUES (3,'SLEEP');
SELECT * FROM tasks;
```

- Note, this is not intended to be a solution to your issue (that as you say isn't explained), but an example of how a TRIGGER can automatically apply changes (in this case after a row has been inserted).

The following results in :-

[image]

You say

> I'd like to know how I could associate an Integer with each individual
>   task.

Each task in the above has it's own unique integer, the **rowid** id or in the case above id as an alias of the **rowid**. [Rowid Tables](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html).

Perhaps even something like :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, user_reference INTEGER, priority DEFAULT (ABS(random() % 100)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for! I really appreciate the help here!